# R, Siny: NavListPanel with top and bottom bar that spans the entire page

Tags: r, shiny, panel

community,

I am trying to write a Gui with shiny that has a title bar at the top, a status bar at the bottom and a navListPanel in the middle. There are a lot of Shiny examples online that helped me come this far:

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(    
        fluidRow(
          column(8,  
                 titlePanel("My Shiny Panel App")
          ),
          column(4,  
                 div(img(src='https://www.bigdatacertification.in/wp-includes/images/hadoopr1.jpg', width="100px", height="80px"), style="float:right")
          )
        ),
        fluidRow(
          navlistPanel(
            tabPanel("Option 1",icon=icon("line-chart"), 
                     "tiny content"
            ),
            tabPanel("Option 2", icon=icon("filter"), 
                     dataTableOutput('table')
            ),
            tabPanel("Option 3", icon=icon("retweet"),
                     "content"
            ),
            tabPanel("Option 4", icon=icon("money"),
                     "content"
            ),
            tabPanel("Option 5", icon=icon("area-chart"), 
                     "content"
            ), 
          widths=c(2,10)
          )
        ),
        fluidRow( 
          column(12, br(),
                 verbatimTextOutput("StausText")
          )
        )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- renderDataTable(iris)
  output$StausText <- renderText("Status: calculating xyz     Connection to DB: established    ....")

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Now I am trying to increase the height of the navListPanel by so much, that it spans the entire page. The status bar at the bottom should still be visible and there should appear scroll bars inside the tabPanels.

In pure HTML I would have done that with "width:100%" but this doesn't seem to work in shiny. I either get tables that are so large that the status bar disappears, or I have to set the height to a fixed value (e.g. 600px) which will obviously not show the intended result on other computers.

I have uploaded two images below, showing what I mean.

Thank you very much 
Matthias

[image]

[image]

In pure html I would simply do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; height:100px; background-color: #abcdef;">
  <h1>Meine App</h1>
</div>

<div style="position:fixed; top:100px; bottom:100px; left:0; right:0; background-color:#F63; overflow:auto;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam  nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut  libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris   sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.  Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci   luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor,  suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a,  consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus.   Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit  amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque  facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi.   Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at  massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum  primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod   orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere   ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis. Aenean  posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero,  sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Pellentesque ut neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In dui  magna, posuere eget, vestibulum et, tempor auctor, justo. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Pellentesque auctor neque   nec urna. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Aenean viverra rhoncus pede. Pellentesque habitant morbi   tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut non enim eleifend felis pretium feugiat. Vivamus quis mi.  Phasellus a est. Phasellus magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis. Curabitur a   felis in nunc fringilla tristique. Morbi mattis ullamcorper velit. Phasellus gravida semper nisi. Nullam vel sem. Pellentesque   libero tortor, tincidunt et, tincidunt eget, semper nec, quam. Sed hendrerit. Morbi ac felis. Nunc egestas, augue at  pellentesque laoreet, felis eros vehicula leo, at malesuada velit leo quis pede. Donec interdum, metus et hendrerit aliquet,   dolor diam sagittis ligula, eget egestas libero turpis vel mi. Nunc nulla. Fusce risus nisl, viverra et, tempor et, pretium in,   sapien. Donec venenatis vulputate lorem. Morbi nec metus. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio. Maecenas ullamcorper, dui et placerat   feugiat, eros pede varius nisi, condimentum viverra felis nunc et lorem. Sed magna 
</div>

<div style="position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; height:100px; background-color:#abcdef;">
   Staus: ...
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you could use `renderPrint` instead of `renderText` to dynamically increase height like [this example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/custom-input-control.html)

Comment: But I don't want to change the height of the status bar. The status bar should be moved to the bottom. I thought this could be done by increasing the height of the Panel element above.

Comment: i'm sharing changes i made so far to solve the issues, hope it helps.
follow [this](https://gist.github.com/chaudharyparth/2caa8d1ba1aef778515e980ce0c4d36d) for updated code

Comment: Thank you very much Parth for your help. You have added the (pageLength = 5) option to the TableOutput. But this doesn't "move" the status bar to the very bottom of the page. It basically looks like in my first screen shot. The status bar is right in the middle of my window. Furthermore, it is not an option to have different pages in the table. I need a long scrollable table on one page. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: I have added a simple html-example that does what I want in the original question. Maybe that makes a bit clearer what I want to do.

Comment: Isn't it possible to somehow change the height of the second fluidRow() object in a way that it spans the entire page without crowding out the status bar at the bottom of the page?

Comment: sorry for late reply @Bernd, the issue is fluidRow() object dimensions can be changed but height of `renderPrint` remains fixed

Comment: i've updated code [here](https://gist.github.com/chaudharyparth/2caa8d1ba1aef778515e980ce0c4d36d) with `statusbar` fixed at end but it works well with `pageLength`=5

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround solution I am using the version below now. It looks a bit unprofessional because it doesn't use the row and col environments of shiny. Instead, it places each row inside a div-object. This is not the intended use of such object (I guess).

Also the width of NavListPanel doesn't add up to 12. For some reason, I get content floating over the right border, if I set the with to c(2,10). Also the width doesn't allow non-integers like c(2,9.5).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- ui <- bootstrapPage(
  div(style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; height:80px; background-color: #abcdef;",
  fluidRow(
    column(8,
           titlePanel("My Shiny Panel App")),
    column(4,
           div(img(src='https://www.bigdatacertification.in/wp-includes/images/hadoopr1.jpg', width="100px", height="80px"), style="float:right;padding-right:10px"))
  )),
  div(style="position:fixed; top:80px; bottom:40px; left:0; right:0; background-color:#F63; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;",
  fluidRow(
        navlistPanel(
          tabPanel("Option 1",icon=icon("line-chart"), 
                   "tiny content"
          ),
          tabPanel("Option 2", icon=icon("filter"),
                   dataTableOutput('table')
          ),
          tabPanel("Option 3", icon=icon("retweet"),
                   "content"
          ),
          tabPanel("Option 4", icon=icon("money"),
                   "content"
          ),
          tabPanel("Option 5", icon=icon("area-chart"), 
                   "content"
          )
          ,
          widths=c(2,9)
        )
  )),
  div(style="position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; height:40px; background-color:#abcdef;",
  fluidRow( 
    column(12,
           verbatimTextOutput("StausText")
  )))
)

server <- server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderDataTable(iris)
  output$StausText <- renderPrint("Status: calculating xyz     Connection to DB: established    ....")

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to do it by just adding `tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".tab-content { height: 83vh; overflow-y: auto !important; }" )))` to your initial code as follows:

```
 ui <- bootstrapPage(    
       fluidRow(
         column(8,  
                titlePanel("My Shiny Panel App")
         ),
         column(4,  
                div(img(src='https://www.bigdatacertification.in/wp-includes/images/hadoopr1.jpg', width="100px", height="80px"), style="float:right")
         )
       ),
       fluidRow(
         navlistPanel(
           tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".tab-content { height: 83vh; overflow-y: auto !important; }" ))),
           tabPanel("Option 1",icon=icon("line-chart"), 
                    "tiny content"
           ),
           tabPanel("Option 2", icon=icon("filter"), 
                    dataTableOutput('table')
           ),
           tabPanel("Option 3", icon=icon("retweet"),
                    "content"
           ),
           tabPanel("Option 4", icon=icon("money"),
                    "content"
           ),
           tabPanel("Option 5", icon=icon("area-chart"), 
                    "content"
           ), 
           widths=c(2,10)
         )
       ),
       fluidRow( 
         column(12, br(),
                verbatimTextOutput("StausText")
         )
       )
     )

     server <- function(input, output) {

       output$table <- renderDataTable(iris)
       output$StausText <- renderText("Status: calculating xyz     Connection to DB: established    ....")

     }

     shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

After adding the above css code your app should have a desired ui as follows:
[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion SBista,

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion SBista,
I understand the tag you added this way: It gives the "tab-content" a height of 83% and the overflow-option of a vertical scroll bar. For some reason I get the vertical scroll bar not inside the tab panel but over the entire page. So that large content would also make the status bar in the bottom disappear.
Also I get a strange "empty option button" in the left menu.